# C# Twitter Api. How to access Twitter's who to follow list?

Tags: c#, wpf, twitter

Is it possible to access Twitter's "Who to follow" list via their API? If yes, could you point me to a tutorial where I can understand and implement it in a pet project I'm working on? Thanks.

Comment: Which api are you using?

Comment: I'm going to use Tweetinvi as a .NET bridge to the Twitter API. I don't know if it has that feature so I was looking to supplement it with Twitter's actual API if that functionality is in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that that function is not documented. Therefore I would suggest using the Twitter REST api:

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/suggestions/%3Aslug

Comment: you could of course add this to the Tweetinvi source for your use and others